# Why isn't Dungeon Defenders showing up in my Steam profile?

Tags: steam, dungeon-defenders

I cannot access my personal Steam Achievements page for the game. I can view the [Global Achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/65800/achievements) page, but not my personal achievements. Whenever I try to go to that, it redirects to my Steam Profile page. I'm worried that I'm going to end up missing out on getting achievements because of this.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Something like this would be best taken up with Steam Support, yes?

Comment: @Thrillho Ticket's been sent for several hours with no response other than the canned "we've received this and will get back to you" so I figured I would ask here to see if anyone else had found anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly a week later, this is the response I received from the Steam helpdesk:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Steam Support.
>
> Technical support for this title is handled by a third party support department - please follow the instructions below to contact the support provider to troubleshoot this issue:
>
> Title: Dungeon Defenders
>   Link: http://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2934-YUDF-1210
>
> Please let us know if you experience further difficulties, or if you have additional questions or concerns.

The Dungeon Defenders forums [FAQ thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2184756) states:

> Q: Steam achievements are not viewable and not working
>
> A: Valve appears to have some global issues with their Stats/Achievements severs and are working to get this fixed.

So I've basically been sent in a circle, seeing as Steam is telling me to talk to Dungeon Defenders and Dungeon Defenders staff say that the issue lies with Steam.

However, according to this thread and a note that has now appeared ingame since it has been patched post-release:

> Q: My achievements aren't working!?
>
> A: **Achievements are only awarded while playing in ranked games.**

The solution I have found to enable viewing my personal achievement page is to **acquire an achievement in Ranked mode**, then your personal achievement page will be properly visible and stop redirecting you to your profile.